# Get second position elements given a criteria

Tags: list-manipulation

I know this is a very simple question but I am fairly new in Mathematica. If I have this list:

```
list={{68.029, 0.0570654}, {68.062, 0.0571538}, {68.095, 
  0.0573135}, {68.128, 0.0573148}, {68.161, 0.0574761}, {68.194, 
  0.0576357}, {68.227, 0.0577004}, {68.261, 0.0574547}, {68.293, 
  0.0576841}, {68.326, 0.0576759}, {68.359, 0.0576677}, {68.392, 
  0.0577419}, {68.426, 0.0576339}, {68.459, 0.0577603}, {68.492, 
  0.0578867}, {68.525, 0.0580131}, {68.558, 0.0581791}, {68.591, 
  0.058209}, {68.624, 0.0583987}, {68.657, 0.0585884}, {68.69, 
  0.0587781}, {68.723, 0.0589489}, {68.756, 0.0589455}, {68.788, 
  0.0593332}, {68.821, 0.0594897}, {68.855, 0.0594118}, {68.888, 
  0.0597297}, {68.921, 0.0598878}, {68.954, 0.0600459}, {68.987, 
  0.0602039}, {69.02, 0.060362}, {69.053, 0.0605185}, {69.086, 
  0.0608349}, {69.119, 0.0609898}, {69.152, 0.0611463}, {69.185, 
  0.0613012}, {69.218, 0.0616191}, {69.252, 0.0615444}, {69.285, 
  0.0618623}, {69.318, 0.0620204}, {69.351, 0.0621785}, {69.384, 
  0.06246}, {69.417, 0.0625516}, {69.45, 0.0626448}, {69.484, 
  0.0625004}, {69.517, 0.0625919}, {69.551, 0.0625077}, {69.584, 
  0.0628557}, {69.617, 0.0630423}, {69.65, 0.0632304}, {69.683, 
  0.0634186}, {69.716, 0.0636083}, {69.749, 0.063798}, {69.781, 
  0.064219}, {69.815, 0.0641775}, {69.848, 0.0643672}, {69.881, 
  0.0647169}, {69.914, 0.0649034}, {69.947, 0.0650916}, {69.981, 
  0.0650469}, {70.014, 0.0652351}, {70.048, 0.065412}, {70.08, 
  0.0659248}, {70.113, 0.0662079}, {70.146, 0.0666526}, {70.179, 
  0.0669357}, {70.211, 0.0675735}, {70.245, 0.0677236}, {70.278, 
  0.0681065}, {70.311, 0.0683279}, {70.345, 0.0684795}, {70.378, 
  0.0689399}, {70.41, 0.0694242}, {70.443, 0.0696725}, {70.476, 
  0.0700807}, {70.509, 0.0703306}, {70.542, 0.0706581}, {70.576, 
  0.0709664}, {70.609, 0.0713477}, {70.641, 0.072117}, {70.674, 
  0.0724967}, {70.707, 0.0729983}, {70.74, 0.0733147}, {70.773, 
  0.0737894}, {70.807, 0.0738729}, {70.84, 0.0743492}, {70.873, 
  0.0748017}, {70.905, 0.0754776}, {70.938, 0.0759174}, {70.971, 
  0.0763589}, {71.004, 0.0768003}, {71.037, 0.0770851}, {71.071, 
  0.0772968}, {71.104, 0.077743}, {71.136, 0.0784236}, {71.17, 
  0.0787969}, {71.202, 0.0794364}, {71.235, 0.0798161}, {71.268, 
  0.0801958}, {71.301, 0.0807354}, {71.335, 0.0808791}, {71.368, 
  0.0813759}, {71.401, 0.081849}, {71.434, 0.0823206}, {71.467, 
  0.0827937}, {71.5, 0.0832652}, {71.533, 0.0837842}, {71.566, 
  0.084327}}
```

How do I get only the second elements of that list that are lower than a given value of the first element, let's say than 70 as to get:

`{0.0570654, 0.0570654,....,0.0650469}`

Thanks

Comment: You can do this with [`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html).

Comment: @JasonB. but how? Could you be more especific please!

Comment: Does this do what you want? `Select[list, #[[1]] < 70 &][[All, 2]]`

Comment: This should do the same, but faster `Pick[list[[All, 2]], UnitStep[list[[All, 1]] - 70], 0]`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher yes! Thank you very much !

Comment: You're welcome.